# Extract data and if a date convert it

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am extracting data from a table to a csv file.

When a date field is to be printed I need to convert to `dd/mm/yyyy`.
Here is the code which i have tried

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlquery); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $key = trim($value);            
        $key = str_replace(',', ' ', $key);   //remove any commas, as they stuff up excel. 
        //Is this a date field? if so convert it to dd/mm/yyyy
        print "$key" . ","; 
    }  
    if ($key > "") fputcsv($output, array('')); 
}
```

Comment: Like date('d/m/Y', strtotime('2014-1-14'))?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to check if the value is in a date format, since mysql_fetch_assoc doesn't include field type information.

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/',$value)) {
  print "$key" . "," . date('d/m/Y',strtotime($value));
}
```

This checks if $value is in the format of four digits, a dash, two digits, a dasha nd two more digits (yyyy-mm-dd) and if so , uses the strtotime function to convert the value to a timestamp, which is used by the date function to format the date string.

By the way, mysql_* functions are deprecated and you should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  list($year, $month, $day) = explode('[-.]', $date); 
    $date = "$day/$month/$year";
```